# scanning buttons from grid WPF in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, button, foreach

I have a WPF project. I want to create a method to scan all the buttons that are part of my grid. Do you know how? Something like

```
foreach (PropertyInfo item in t.GetType().GetProperties())
```

Just for grid in WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job.

```
public List<Button> GetButtonsFromGrid (Grid grid)
{
    return grid.Children.OfType<Button>().ToList<Button>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the very limited information you have provided:

```
foreach (Button b in grid1.Children)
{
    MessageBox.Show(b.Name);
}
```